# A newbie to C: I need to read this line of data from file "-2.628489e-03 -1.194542e-03 -1.073491e-02 "

Tags: c

I've tried %f %g %e and the long version of the same.

eg. `fscanf(inFile,"%g %g %g ",&c0,&c1,&c2);`

results in

> > -1.1546e+09 -1.16415e+09 -1.13768e+09

Could someone please tell me what format to use? Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string

Comment: How are `c0` `c1` and `c2` declared?

Comment: @nonsensical: Thx for the ref, I looked it up.  I reformat the data file (without the " " <space> at the very end of the line) and re-read file with the code. It works!

Comment: @Currie: as floats for the above example.

Comment: @Amar: most scanf conversion specifiers (all except `"%c"`, `"%[...]"`, and, for a differente reason, `"%n"`) include ignoring leading whitespace. Your example format string and `"%g%g%g "` do exactly the same thing. I'd go as far as say that spaces inside the scanf format string are, most of the time, redundant ... and some times even an error.

Comment: @Amar Rampal, you're welcome. I too fell into that trap when I first used scanf and the likes. A `%f` will only be "consumed" when you press space or enter, and if you have other spaces in there it will wait for them, a real pain. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Use the correct formats

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    float f1, f2, f3;
    double d1, d2, d3;
    long double l1, l2, l3;

    fscanf(stdin, "%f%f%f", &f1, &f2, &f3);    /* scan floats */
    fscanf(stdin, "%lf%lf%lf", &d1, &d2, &d3); /* scan doubles */
    fscanf(stdin, "%Lf%Lf%Lf", &l1, &l2, &l3); /* scan long doubles */

    printf("floats: %f %f %f\n", f1, f2, f3);   /* print floats (they're automagically converted to doubles) */
    printf("doubles: %f %f %f\n", d1, d2, d3);  /* print doubles */
    printf("longs: %Lf %Lf %Lf\n", l1, l2, l3); /* print long doubles */

    return 0;
}
```

See [code "running" at ideone with your inputs](http://ideone.com/wDpKGX)

Comment: I've never seen ideone.com, thanx for the tip :)

Comment: Thanks for the code. I did try all of these formats as well with my file to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

case of c? is double

```
double c0,c1,c2;
fsscanf(inFile, "%lf %lf %lf", &c0,&c1,&c2);
```

case of c? is float

```
float c0,c1,c2;
fsscanf(inFile, "%f %f %f", &c0,&c1,&c2);
```